# Send a telnet command and kill connection without waiting for a response

Tags: ruby, automation, telnet

I am trying to make a telnet connection and send a command which forces a reboot and then kill the connection. So far i have:

```
require 'net/telnet'
host = 192.168.20.11
connection = Net::Telnet::new("Host" => host)
connection.login("User")
connection.cmd("Reboot")
```

This works and achieves what i want it to, however the program then waits for feedback from the reboot command which there is none because it is rebooting, the program therefore fails. Is there a way i can send the command and then close the connection without waiting for feedback? This would allow me to continue through the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't see any way documented to handle this.  You might be able to fake it with something like this:

```
begin
  connection.cmd("String" => "Reboot", "Timeout" => 0.1)
rescue # I'm not sure what that will raise, but you should rescue that specific error here
  nil
end
```

I have to ask though, is there any way you can use `ssh` as opposed to `telnet`?

Comment: That might be worth a shot, might give that a go. As for ssh I am just looking into that now, that crossed my mind after posting this. But never done ssh in ruby either so I am running through the instructions. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: `net/ssh` is far more refined than telnet (not to mention infinitely more secure).

Comment: Your answer was bang on. The reboot causes a drop in the connection as we knew and rescue allowed me to well, 'rescue' it and kill it gracefully. Thanks